# deleting characters between two different keywords

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

i have a string like below.

stg = "Abel read (reading)|book(peripheral)~Q27.8#basillary NEC~Q28.1|| "

### Requirement:

Need to delete the character between two keywords ~ and # and then print the remaining.

### Output:

"Abel read (reading)|book(peripheral)basillary NEC~Q28.1|| "

Comment: What have you tried so far? Some regex magic should do the job

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try finding similar questions on stackoverflow?

Comment: stg = "Abel read (reading)|book(peripheral)~Q27.8#basillary NEC~Q28.1|| "


stg.split("~")[0] + stg.split("#")[1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **[string.find](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/find)** method

```
stg = "Abel read (reading)|book(peripheral)~Q27.8#basillary NEC~Q28.1|| "
start = stg.find( '~' )
end = stg.find( '#' )

if start != -1 and end != -1:
    result = stg.replace(stg[start:end+1], "")
print result
```

**Output**:

```
Abel read (reading)|book(peripheral)basillary NEC~Q28.1||
```

Comment: hi wow, it got worked. thanks rakesh

Comment: You are welcome:)